# How do I turn off the display

Tags: command-line, display

Is there any key kombination or terminal code that turns the display off? It should work like when you lock the screen: As soon as you move the mouse the display should turn on again (without the need of doing a login).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
xset dpms force off
```

You can look at `man xset` for more details. You can also set `dpms` to `standby` and `suspend`, but I think how this works depends on your hardware.

Comment: would that also work if I would use fglrx(-updates) as my display driver?

Comment: @Delta I'm actually not too sure.